# when is the size of a QWidget in a QGridLayout specified?

Tags: qt, qt4, qwidget, qlayout

in my Qt-application I add a QGridLayout to the main window. Afterwards, i include some `QLabels`, some with `QSizePolicy::Minimum`, others with `QSizePolicy::Expanding`.
I add the labels into the grid in the `resizeEvent` of the window. 
At the end of the `resizeEvent`-method, I put out the height of one label.
surprisingly, i always get the height of the whole window, never mind, which label's height i want to know.

when the `resizeEvent` is called for the second time, i get the label's height, which is much smaller than the windowHeight.

The Labels are definitly initialized before in the constructor of the mainWindow. There, I also set the central Layout to the qGridLayout.

Can anybody tell me, why I'm getting such awesome values for the label's height?

Thank you in advance

Robby

Comment: Adding items to a widget's layout is almost certainly going to result in further layout/geometry update events.  For that reason it shouldn't come as any great surprise that the *final* sizes aren't immediately available.  What's the problem you're actually trying to solve -- or is it just curiosity?

Comment: Depending on the resolution ratio, i want to show the labels on the top or on the right side. I put this functionality (removing the Widgets and adding them again) into the `resizeEvent`. I tried to set a `QPixmap` to the last label, so I had to pass the `QSize` of the label to  `label->setPixmap(pixmap.scaled(...->width(), ...->height(), Qt::KeepAspectRatio));`  There, i found this strange behavior.